# Core Data lightweight migration crash

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, core-data-migration

I updating my database with a lightweight migration.  If I do the update on my device through xcode in debug mode everything runs fine.  If I load the app through iTunes as a archive file it will crash before loading the rootViewController.  This only happens with my large test database >100mb.  I don't get anything useful in the crash log and am not sure what to do with this.

His is the only relevant line I can find in the crash log.

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this would be reflected in the crash report (It would say something about failing to launch in time) but iOS devices expect you to get a view on the screen (or for ApplicationDidFinishLaunching to finish, I'm not sure exactly what it looks for) in a certain amount of time or it just gives up and closes the app.  If you are doing a significant amount of work you'll want to get some kind of screen up before you start that work.  Unfortunately this doesn't happen in a debug environment so it's a pain to test.

Comment: Thanks this was the fix but it was a bear to move all the database loading out of the app delegate.